# > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 61

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, build-script

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/bradodenath/StudioProjects/allegrias/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/bradodenath/.gradle/caches/6.7.1/scripts/1s73qcb50lg0rbrzpvq7gi0ih).
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 61

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 300ms
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           752ms

Flutter Fix ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using    │
for Gradle.                                                                                      │

> │                                                                                                  │
> To fix this issue, consult the migration guide at docs.flutter.dev/go/android-java-gradle-error. │
> └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
> Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
> Process finished with exit code 1

I am getting this error running an Android Studio APK build with jbr-17 (17.0.7) under the flutter system

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.